# Rails deleting record in join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console

I have two associated tables, 'releases' & 'tracks' which contain the fields 'name' and 'isrc' respectively.

I am trying to remove all tracks from the database when release.name is equal to a certain value, e.g "Thriller".

The relationship here is that 'track' belongs_to a 'release' and a 'release' has_many 'tracks'.

Can anyone help me with how to achieve this within the Rails console?

Comment: please paste associations here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your release model:

```
has_many :tracks, dependent: :destroy
```

This will remove all the tracks associated with a release from the database when you destroy a release.

You can test this by doing something like this in the console

```
release = Realse.where(name:"Thriller").first
release_id = release.id
release.destroy
tracks = Track.where(release_id:release_id)
```

The variable tracks should now be empty.

Answer (score 0):

it should work:

```
Track.delete_all("release_id in ?", Release.select("id").where(name: 'Thriller'))
```

Thanks